# ubuntu 11.10 btrfs errors after every reboot

Tags: 11.10, filesystem, btrfs

I installed a new system when oneiric was released

I am also using gnome classic and have the following layout:

```
/dev/sda3 on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,relatime,subvol=@)
/dev/sda3 on /home type btrfs (rw,noatime,relatime,subvol=@home)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,noatime,relatime,commit=0)
```

The machine is a thinkpad 410s (ssd, 8gb of ram, i5, integrated video card)

Every time I reboot(gracefully) it looks like the btrfs has to be checked (there are a lot of reads or writes going on) and it says it found errors then looks like it corrects them and then goes on with the boot.

Any idea where can I look to know what is going on? Anybody knows of a known bug in the conditions I am describing or something similar?

I want to troubleshoot it but I do not know where to start looking.

Comment: Can you split this up into two questions? This system works best when there's one question per issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a solid-state disk (SSD) you might want to put the 'discard' option in your /etc/fstab file. This enables the [TRIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM) command.

You might want to run `sudo btrfsck /dev/sda3` to check your system for errors.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs

Comment: My ssd does not support TRIM (is a crappy toshiba drive). 
I will check the btrfsck and see what I find

Answer (score 0):

Use "disk utility" that you have on ubuntu. Make some scans and check the ssd's status. Other then that i hope you find better help somewhere somehow.

Comment: You can run it with `palimpsest`.